# Como converter uma app android para ios

Tags: android, ios, mobile, framework

Eu terminei uma aplicação Android, Muitas pessoas me pediram para entregar uma versão para IOS.

Fiz pesquisas e vi que é possível usando Html5, Css e javascript.
Neste caso eu teria que refazer a minha aplicação.

Existem uma framework que permite eu converter Android -- IOS ?

Comment: Existem algumas alternativas para isso. Existem várias plataformas que permitem usar código Java no iOS, cada uma com suas características. Eu, por exemplo, trabalho para a [TotalCross](http://www.totalcross.com), que permite que o programador escreva em Java e rode seu código em múltiplas plataformas, como Windows Desktop, Android e iOS com velocidade comparável à de código nativo

Comment: Converter acho meio difícil, sempre vai ser complicado. O melhor seria vc ter começado a programar já no xamarin.

Comment: Eu posso usar o Swift no Windows?